# passing model parameters to R's predict() function robustly

Tags: r, lexical-scope, dynamic-scope

I am trying to use R to fit a linear model and make predictions. My model includes some constant side parameters that are not in the data frame. Here's a simplified version of what I'm doing:

```
dat <- data.frame(x=1:5,y=3*(1:5))
b <- 1
mdl <- lm(y~I(b*x),data=dat)
```

Unfortunately the model object now suffers from a dangerous scoping issue: `lm()` does not save `b` as part of `mdl`, so when `predict()` is called, it has to reach back into the environment where `b` was defined. Thus, if subsequent code changes the value of `b`, the predict value will change too:

```
y1 <- predict(mdl,newdata=data.frame(x=3)) # y1 == 9
b <- 5
y2 <- predict(mdl,newdata=data.frame(x=3)) # y2 == 45
```

How can I force `predict()` to use the original `b` value instead of the changed one? Alternatively, is there some way to control where `predict()` looks for the variable, so I can ensure it gets the desired value? In practice I cannot include `b` as part of the `newdata` data frame, because in my application, `b` is a vector of parameters that does not have the same size as the data frame of new observations.

Please note that I have greatly simplified this relative to my actual use case, so I need a robust general solution and not just ad-hoc hacking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`eval(substitute` the value into the quoted expression

```
mdl <- eval(substitute(lm(y~I(b*x),data=dat), list(b=b)))

mdl
# Call:
# lm(formula = y ~ I(1 * x), data = dat)
# ...
```

Comment: Wow, that's neat. Only downside is it makes `str(mdl)` more ugly because it's full of the substituted values. But I can live with that for now, unless you can think of an even better approach? Thanks!

Comment: @Paul I'm not sure what you mean?  Because there are numbers in place of "b"?  or something else?

Comment: yes, in practice I'm doing `cut(x,breaks=v)` and your solution is expanding `v` into `c(0,0.8,1.7,...)` wherever `v` is found in the `mdl` object. This is only an aesthetic issue though; at the end of the day, your solution does the job exactly as required.

Comment: @Paul ok, try `mdl <- local({b=b; lm(y ~ I(b*x), data=dat) })`, maybe that is prettier

Comment: Yes, that fixes the aesthetic issue. Could you possibly explain how is R still finding the original `b` value even after I change it in the global workspace?

Comment: @Paul you probably just want to read the `?local` documentation (the environment stuff can be confusing and it will do a better job than me), but `local` creates a new enviroment where you can define variables for the expression.  For example, if you instead did `mdl <- local({ b=b; lm(y ~ I(b*x), data=dat) }, envir=.GlobalEnv)`, it wouldn't work when you redefine `b` in the global environment.

Comment: Thanks. After reading the docs I was a bit puzzled about where the new environment spawned by `local()` lived. But I found this code illuminating: `my_env=new.env();
mdl <- local({b<-1; lm(y ~ I(b*x), data=dat) },envir=my_env);
ls(my_env)`, which outputs `"b"`

Comment: @Paul yes, that is a perfect example :)

Answer (score 0):

We could also use `bquote`

```
mdl <- eval(bquote(lm(y~I(.(b)*x), data=dat)))
mdl

#Call:
#lm(formula = y ~ I(1 * x), data = dat)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)     I(1 * x)  
#  9.533e-15    3.000e+00
```

According to `?bquote` description

> ‘bquote’ quotes its
>        argument except that terms wrapped in ‘.()’ are evaluated in the
>        specified ‘where’ environment.